# Can't connect to nodejs on ubuntu xenial

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I am using vagrant to create a machine on virtualbox. The machine only has a fresh install of Ubuntu (updated) and node.

**node server.js** works find with the installation in my system. Can see the "Hello world" on chrome.
But when I ssh into my machine and use **node server.js** on the server, I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on chrome.

Here is all my code

Vagrantfile:

```
  Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.8.6"

  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
      config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

      config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
      config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]

      config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |virtualbox|
        virtualbox.name = "vagrant"
        virtualbox.memory = 512
        virtualbox.cpus = 1
        virtualbox.gui = false
      end
  end
```

server.js

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

software versions:

- windows 10 Home
- vagrant 1.8.6
- virtualbox 5.1.8
- ubuntu xenial 64
- node v6.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running inside Vagrant, the address `127.0.0.1` does not necessarily map to 'localhost'. Remove the hostname and you should be fine:

```
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening ${port}/`);
});
```

Omitting [the hostname defaults to `0.0.0.0`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback)